# Selenium API can't find the desired element in my Python program

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium to automatically download songs from a website, but something is going wrong when I try to find the desired element. I used method `find_elements_by_xpath()`. Go to http://moresound.tk/music/# to visit the website. The error is `TimeoutException`, but my web browser has already shown the element I want. Can you tell me what's wrong?

```py
    # coding: utf-8
    from selenium import webdriver
    import re
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir','d://')
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList',2)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting',False)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='H:/fire_fox_driver/geckodriver')
    driver.get('http://moresound.tk/music/#')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("search_input").send_keys(u'周杰伦')
    driver.find_element_by_id("search_btn").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
    '//body/div[@id="main"]//li')))
    song = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body/div[@id="main"]//li')
    song.click()
```

The error is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):File ...
     line 23, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//body/div[@id="main"]//li')))
  File ...
 line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

[image: Error screenshot].

[image: Website page screenshot].

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is also selecting a hidden `<li>` which will fail the clickable check:

[image]

Instead, select only the actual search result `<li>` items in a more specific wrapper:

`//div[@id="MS_search_result"]//li`

Which does not return that first item:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Firefox doesnt interact with Elements which are not actually visible.

Make sure if you are checking with the latest Firefox version and its corresponding driver.

If that doesnt work, try checking the same code with Chrome.